# Align the cube's nearest face to the camera

Tags: java, math

I have a cube and `4x4` transformation matrix Cube is rotated randomly I need to find the nearest face of cube regarding to camera and rotate the cube by aligning that face to the camera.

How can I do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you define the nearest side? Centre of side? Any point in side? Pane of side? These could all lead to different solutions.

Comment: Which programming languages or software libraries are you using?

Comment: @AndersonGreen no libs. java gles20, custom camera, matrix, vector etc classes.

Comment: *I have an animal, vegetable, or mineral. How can I tell what color it is?*. You need to [edit] your question to provide more details about what you're asking, including the language and libraries, if you want us to help.

Comment: @fejese lets say cube is at the origin 0,0,0 and it is a unit cube:  (-1,-1,-1)(1,1,1) and camera is at the point (0,0,-2)

Comment: @developer2011, let's say that, that's something at least but the goals and the expectations are still a bit vague. Just look at JohnPercivalHackworth's answer for some possibilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without getting into a bunch of math, here is a strategy.

1. Identify the face nearest to the camera under some criteria. Two possible criteria for determining the closest face are:

   a. Finding the closest face based on the Euclidian distance between the face centroid and the camera's centroid.

   b. Determine which face normal vector is most close to parallel to the camera view vector and has a direction that is opposite to the view vector. This assumes that the face normal vectors point outwards.
2. Once you've identified the 'closest' face, determine the inverse transform to that will align the face normal with the camera view vector. Any decent 3D computer graphics text will serve as a reasonable guide.

Comment: Some of users just preferred commenting and only criticized. down votes were bonus like salt and pepper :) thank you for you kind response and answer. It seems you absolutely deserved your reputation in here. Happy holidays. Thank you again.